# SQL Inner/Sub group wise Query for a specific scenario

Tags: sql, group-by, subquery

I have a table as below

> Schema: ID | Category | Keyword | Bid Price

Write a sql to fetch out top 5 keywords based on the bid price per category.

Details:

Table definition considered on oracle 10.x:

```
create table test (
    ID number,
    Category varchar (20),
    Keyword varchar (20),
    BidPrice number
);
```

Data:

```
insert into test values (1, 'Category-A', 'Keyword-A1', 110);
insert into test values (2, 'Category-A', 'Keyword-A2', 121);
insert into test values (3, 'Category-A', 'Keyword-A3', 130);
insert into test values (4, 'Category-A', 'Keyword-A4', 125);
insert into test values (5, 'Category-A', 'Keyword-A5', 115);
insert into test values (6, 'Category-A', 'Keyword-A6', 133);
insert into test values (7, 'Category-B', 'Keyword-B1', 105);
insert into test values (8, 'Category-B', 'Keyword-B2', 111);
insert into test values (9, 'Category-B', 'Keyword-B3', 108);
insert into test values (10, 'Category-B', 'Keyword-B4', 128);
insert into test values (11, 'Category-B', 'Keyword-B5', 144);
insert into test values (12, 'Category-B', 'Keyword-B6', 101);
insert into test values (13, 'Category-C', 'Keyword-C1', 150);
insert into test values (14, 'Category-C', 'Keyword-C2', 137);
insert into test values (15, 'Category-C', 'Keyword-C3', 126);
insert into test values (16, 'Category-C', 'Keyword-C4', 121);
insert into test values (17, 'Category-C', 'Keyword-C5', 112);
insert into test values (18, 'Category-C', 'Keyword-C6', 118);
```

**Output expected:**

```
KEYWORD         CATEGORY      BIDPRICE
--------------  ------------  ----------
Keyword-A6      Category-A    133
Keyword-A3      Category-A    130
Keyword-A4      Category-A    125
Keyword-A2      Category-A    121
Keyword-A5      Category-A    115
Keyword-B5      Category-B    144
Keyword-B4      Category-B    128
Keyword-B2      Category-B    111
Keyword-B3      Category-B    108
Keyword-B1      Category-B    105
Keyword-C1      Category-C    150
Keyword-C2      Category-C    137
Keyword-C3      Category-C    126
Keyword-C4      Category-C    121
Keyword-C6      Category-C    118
```

*Note:  Answer has to be only in SQL without use of any Oracle or database specific function.*

Comment: isn't it `6, 'Category-A', 'Keyword-A6', 133);` ?

Comment: i.e. shouldn't the row 6 (containing in fact the *highest* price in the category) be included in Category A's top 5 in your output?

Comment: You are right 133 should be included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this query but it is leaving the 6th row if it is biggest.  Can any one help on this?

```
select a.keyword, a.category, a.bidprice
from
  test a,
  (
    select b.id, b.category
    from test b
    where (select distinct(c.category) from test c where b.category=c.category) = b.category
  ) xx
where a.id in (select ss.id from test ss where a.category=ss.category and rownum<=5)
group by a.category, a.bidprice, a.keyword
order by a.category, a.bidprice desc;
```

Guys,

I solved it, please consider this:

```
select a.keyword, a.category, a.bidprice
from
  test a,
  (
    select b.id, b.category
    from test b
    where (select distinct(c.category) from test c where b.category=c.category) = b.category
    order by b.bidprice desc
  ) xx
where a.id in (
  select id
  from (select dd.id, dd.category from test dd order by dd.bidprice desc) ss
  where a.category=ss.category
    and rownum<=5
)
group by a.category, a.bidprice, a.keyword
order by a.category, a.bidprice desc;
```

Comment: Note that `rownum` is an Oracle-specific feature. (Thus your solution is not pure SQL).

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
select KEYWORD, CATEGORY ,BIDPRICE 
from 
(
  select KEYWORD, CATEGORY ,BIDPRICE , 
         ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Category order by BidPrice desc)  as rn
  from test
) a
where a.rn <= 5;
```

## [Sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/03cc4/17)

Comment: @JohnWoo: * inside the sub query doesn't it seems .. I have replaced * with column name.. now its working...

Comment: Sorry Joe,  I asked about only SQL, no use of any Oracle function.

Comment: @shaILU: There's nothing Oracle-specific in this answer. (If you are worried about ROW_NUMBER(), it is part of the standard and is supported by many SQL products.)

Answer (score 3):

make use of **[`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm)**

```
SELECT KEYWORD ,CATEGORY, BIDPRICE
FROM
(
  SELECT KEYWORD ,CATEGORY, BIDPRICE,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CATEGORY ORDER BY BIDPRICE DESC) rn
  FROM test
) a
WHERE rn <= 5
ORDER BY CATEGORY, BIDPRICE DESC
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/03cc4/2)

Comment: Sorry Joe, I asked about only SQL, no use of any Oracle function.

Comment: @shaILU `SQL` means Structured Query Language. What RDBMS you are using? (*Relational Database Management System*)? eg `SQL Server`, `Oracle`, `MySQL`, `PostgreSQL`, or what? :D

Comment: I know SQL abbreviation John.  But actually project requirement says, "we do not want to use RDBMS specific function.  Only SQL is required.".  Still we are using Oracle 10g John.